# My custom context menu additions are doubling up when right clicking any folder in the Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

So I've spent quite a long time customizing my Win10 context menu to get it just right:

### Folder Context Menu:

---

[image: Folder Context Menu]

### Folder Background Context Menu:

---

[image: Folder Background]

I'm really satisfied with everything after all that tweaking, but one problem remains. If I right click on any folder in the Navigation Pane, the menu doubles up. It shows entries for both `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory` AND `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background`. Image for reference:

[image: Double Context Menus]

Is there a way to stop this from happening, or is this just how Windows works? I'm hoping someone around here knows some kind of hack, because it's... very ugly. I have no idea why Windows is invoking the Directory\Background shell menu when I'm explicitly right clicking on a Directory.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to happen if the menu item key names are identical. If you look a the default `cmd`entry, for example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"
"Extended"=""
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

This proved true with a user-created item as well.

- Identical key names, even with different `(Default)` values, did not "duplicate". So take a look at your registry entries, or export and edit your question with the relevant export files.